# Objective C Localized Audio Files not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation

I have been ploughing along with my learning of objective c and have got my app doing more or less everything I want it to do. I have the correct audio playing when certain buttons are pressed.

I have run in to some difficulty when localizing my audio file.

I have localized other elements of my app with no issue, for example I have used different images and button backgrounds and text by localizing in the same way but when I localize audio i run in to some issues and I can not find a solutions online as I normally do.

So as I said the issue only occurs when the file is localized, it effects the original language (where it was working before localizing the file) and the other languages (in this case French)

So the code I am using on my button is:

```
- (IBAction)domesticButtonClicked:(id)sender
{

    NSString* resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];

    resourcePath = [resourcePath stringByAppendingString:@"/localize-test.wav"];

    // NSLog(@"Path to play: %@", resourcePath);
    NSError* err;

    //Initialize our player pointing to the path to our resource
    domesticSound = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:
                     [NSURL fileURLWithPath:resourcePath] error:&err];

    if( err ){
        //bail!
        NSLog(@"Failed with reason: %@", [err localizedDescription]);
    }
    else{
        //set our delegate and begin playback
        domesticSound.delegate = self;
        [domesticSound play];
        domesticSound.numberOfLoops = 0;
        domesticSound.currentTime = 0;
        domesticSound.volume = 1.0;

    }

}


}
```

So when this runs, instead of it playing the sound as it should I see the following in my output:

Failed with reason: The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 2003334207.)

Can anyone shed any light on this for me?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

Thanks Marcus Adams, what you suggested does work but I can not use it on some buttons as i can not declare it every time.

So the reason the audio file is declared that way is so the audio file can be altered depending on the number of times the button has been clicked. Maybe this will help in getting my issue resolved.

```
- (IBAction)domestic03ButtonClicked:(id)sender
{

    static int imageNumber = 0;

    NSString* resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];


    if (imageNumber == 0) {
        domestic03ImageContainer.image = domestic300;
        resourcePath = [resourcePath stringByAppendingString:@"/smb_coin1.wav"];
        imageNumber++;
    }

    else if (imageNumber == 1) {
        domestic03ImageContainer.image = domestic301;
        resourcePath = [resourcePath stringByAppendingString:@"/smb_coin2.wav"];
        imageNumber++;
    }

    else if (imageNumber == 2) {
        domestic03ImageContainer.image = domestic302;
        resourcePath = [resourcePath stringByAppendingString:@"/smb_coin3.wav"];
        imageNumber++;
    }

    else if (imageNumber == 3) {
        domestic03ImageContainer.image = domestic303;
        resourcePath = [resourcePath stringByAppendingString:@"/smb_coin4.wav"];
        imageNumber++;
    }

    else if (imageNumber == 4) {
        domestic03ImageContainer.image = domestic304;
        resourcePath = [resourcePath stringByAppendingString:@"/smb_coin5.wav"];
        imageNumber = 0;
    }


    // NSLog(@"Path to play: %@", resourcePath);
    NSError* err;

    //Initialize our player pointing to the path to our resource
    domesticSound = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:
                     [NSURL fileURLWithPath:resourcePath] error:&err];

    if( err ){
        //bail!
        NSLog(@"Failed with reason: %@", [err localizedDescription]);
    }
    else{
        //set our delegate and begin playback
        domesticSound.delegate = self;
        [domesticSound play];
        domesticSound.numberOfLoops = 0;
        domesticSound.currentTime = 0;
        domesticSound.volume = 1.0;

    }

    domestic03ImageContainer.Alpha = 1;

}
```

Comment: you should only check _err_ if _domesticSound == nil_, when the API has an NSError** in/out argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to use just this for your path, assuming you've put the resource directly in the proper localized folder:

```
NSString* resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"localize-test"
                                                         ofType:@"wav"];
```

Comment: Hey ok this works for the specific question above however I am going to edit my question as there is an issue on another button that plays a different sound for each click - it cycles through sounds. This is reason I have used this code on the button and not your way of doing it. Any idea how I can solve this. Give me a minute and I will edit my question so you can see what I mean.

Comment: I used this to get it working as inside each if statement instead of using: `resourcePath = [resourcePath stringByAppendingString:@"/smb_coin1.wav"];` i used `resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"localize-test"ofType:@"wav"];` and he presto it works now for localization. That's @Marcus

Answer (score 0):

You should only check *err* if *domesticSound == nil*. This is generally true for APIs that take an *NSError*** in/out argument. (*err* is not guaranteed to be written to upon success.)

You should also initialize *err* to nil!